# Foreign key constraint fails - Cannot add items to cart after database restoration with missing tables

Tags: database, magento-1.4

I Would really appreciate any insights into this matter,
I have Magento 1.4.1.1 which I tried to restore the MySQL database for from the cpanel interface. Seeing as there were missing tables I ran the magento database repair tool. Now seems that there are some inconsistencies in the database and there is an exception thrown when I try to add an item to the cart from the frontend:

The results of the database repair tool:

```
Add missing table "m2epro_lock_item"
Add missing table "m2epro_locked_object"
Add missing table "m2epro_marketplace"
Add missing table "m2epro_migration_v6"
Add missing table "m2epro_order"
Add missing table "m2epro_order_change"
Add missing table "m2epro_order_item"
Add missing table "m2epro_order_log"
Add missing table "m2epro_order_repair"
Add missing table "m2epro_play_account"
Add missing table "m2epro_play_item"
Add missing table "m2epro_play_listing"
Add missing table "m2epro_play_listing_other"
Add missing table "m2epro_play_listing_product"
Add missing table "m2epro_play_listing_product_variation"
Add missing table "m2epro_play_listing_product_variation_option"
Add missing table "m2epro_play_marketplace"
Add missing table "m2epro_play_order"
Add missing table "m2epro_play_order_item"
Add missing table "m2epro_play_processed_inventory"
Add missing table "m2epro_play_template_selling_format"
Add missing table "m2epro_play_template_synchronization"
Add missing table "m2epro_primary_config"
Add missing table "m2epro_processing_request"
Add missing table "m2epro_product_change"
Add missing table "m2epro_stop_queue"
Add missing table "m2epro_synchronization_config"
Add missing table "m2epro_synchronization_log"
Add missing table "m2epro_synchronization_run"
Add missing table "m2epro_template_selling_format"
Add missing table "m2epro_template_synchronization"
Add missing table "m2epro_wizard"
Add missing table "newsletter_problem"
Add missing table "newsletter_queue"
Add missing table "newsletter_queue_link"
Add missing table "newsletter_queue_store_link"
Add missing table "newsletter_subscriber"
Add missing table "newsletter_template"
Add missing table "paygate_authorizenet_debug"
Add missing table "paypal_api_debug"
Add missing table "paypal_settlement_report"
Add missing table "paypal_settlement_report_row"
Add missing table "paypaluk_api_debug"
Add missing table "poll"
Add missing table "poll_answer"
Add missing table "poll_store"
Add missing table "poll_vote"
Add missing table "product_alert_price"
Add missing table "product_alert_stock"
Add missing table "rating"
Add missing table "rating_entity"
Add missing table "rating_option"
Add missing table "rating_option_vote"
Add missing table "rating_option_vote_aggregated"
Add missing table "rating_store"
Add missing table "rating_title"
Add missing table "report_compared_product_index"
Add missing table "report_event"
Add missing table "report_event_types"
Add missing table "report_viewed_product_index"
Add missing table "review"
Add missing table "review_detail"
Add missing table "review_entity"
Add missing table "review_entity_summary"
Add missing table "review_status"
Add missing table "review_store"
Add missing table "sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily"
Add missing table "sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly"
Add missing table "sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly"
Add missing table "sales_billing_agreement"
Add missing table "sales_billing_agreement_order"
Add missing table "sales_flat_creditmemo"
Add missing table "sales_flat_creditmemo_comment"
Add missing table "sales_flat_creditmemo_grid"
Add missing table "sales_flat_creditmemo_item"
Add missing table "sales_flat_invoice"
Add missing table "sales_flat_invoice_comment"
Add missing table "sales_flat_invoice_grid"
Add missing table "sales_flat_invoice_item"
Add missing table "sales_flat_order"
Add missing table "sales_flat_order_address"
Add missing table "sales_flat_order_grid"
Add missing table "sales_flat_order_item"
Add missing table "sales_flat_order_payment"
Add missing table "sales_flat_order_status_history"
Add missing table "sales_flat_quote"
Add missing table "sales_flat_quote_address"
Add missing table "sales_flat_quote_address_item"
Add missing table "sales_flat_quote_item"
Add missing table "sales_flat_quote_item_option"
Add missing table "sales_flat_quote_payment"
Add missing table "sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate"
Add missing table "sales_flat_shipment"
Add missing table "sales_flat_shipment_comment"
Add missing table "sales_flat_shipment_grid"
Add missing table "sales_flat_shipment_item"
Add missing table "sales_flat_shipment_track"
Add missing table "sales_invoiced_aggregated"
Add missing table "sales_invoiced_aggregated_order"
Add missing table "sales_order_aggregated_created"
Add missing table "sales_order_tax"
Add missing table "sales_payment_transaction"
Add missing table "sales_recurring_profile"
Add missing table "sales_recurring_profile_order"
Add missing table "sales_refunded_aggregated"
Add missing table "sales_refunded_aggregated_order"
Add missing table "sales_shipping_aggregated"
Add missing table "sales_shipping_aggregated_order"
Add missing table "salesrule"
Add missing table "salesrule_coupon"
Add missing table "salesrule_coupon_usage"
Add missing table "salesrule_customer"
Add missing table "salesrule_label"
Add missing table "sendfriend_log"
Add missing table "shipping_tablerate"
Add missing table "sitemap"
Add missing table "tag"
Add missing table "tag_properties"
Add missing table "tag_relation"
Add missing table "tag_summary"
Add missing table "tax_calculation"
Add missing table "tax_calculation_rate"
Add missing table "tax_calculation_rate_title"
Add missing table "tax_calculation_rule"
Add missing table "tax_class"
Add missing table "tax_order_aggregated_created"
Add missing table "weee_discount"
Add missing table "weee_tax"
Add missing table "westpac_quickgateway"
Add missing table "widget"
Add missing table "widget_instance"
Add missing table "widget_instance_page"
Add missing table "widget_instance_page_layout"
Add missing table "wishlist"
Add missing table "wishlist_item"
```

The error received from the exception log after adding an item to the cart:

```
2015-05-17T04:39:10+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`user_database`.`report_event`, CONSTRAINT `FK_REPORT_EVENT_TYPE` FOREIGN KEY (`event_type_id`) REFERENCES `report_event_types` (`event_type_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
Trace: #0 /home/user/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/user/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(468): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#2 /home/user/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `re...', Array)
#3 /home/user/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(333): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `re...', Array)
#4 /home/user/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(546): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `re...', Array)
#5 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(414): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('report_event', Array)
#6 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(306): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Reports_Model_Event))
#7 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Event/Observer.php(69): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#8 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Event/Observer.php(210): Mage_Reports_Model_Event_Observer->_event(4, '240')
#9 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1228): Mage_Reports_Model_Event_Observer->checkoutCartAddProduct(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1209): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Reports_Model_Event_Observer), 'checkoutCartAdd...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home/user/public_html/app/Mage.php(416): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_quote_ite...', Array)
#12 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(379): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_ite...', Array)
#13 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item/Abstract.php(54): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_beforeSave()
#14 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php(97): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract->_beforeSave()
#15 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(304): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item->_beforeSave()
#16 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Collection/Abstract.php(500): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#17 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract->save()
#18 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(307): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->_afterSave()
#19 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(357): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#20 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(184): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->save()
#21 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->addAction()
#22 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('add')
#23 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(177): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#24 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(304): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#25 /home/user/public_html/app/Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#26 /home/user/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#27 {main}
```

any thhoughts on how this can be remediated?